# Symfony2 - Error when trying to get post count for a specific year

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, count

I am trying to create a query to find all posts within the year 2014.

I have the following but the error appears:

```
[Syntax Error] line 0, col 88: Error: Expected end of string, got '00'
```

What's wrong with my query?

```
public function getPostCountByYear()
{
    $query = $this
        ->createQueryBuilder('post')
        ->where('created >= 2014-01-01 00:00:00 AND created < 2015-01-01 00:00:00');
    $query->select('COUNT(post)');

    $year = $query
        ->getQuery()
        ->getSingleScalarResult();

    return $year;
}
```

Comment: `->where('created >= :date')->where('created < :date1')` and bind `?date` `->setParameter('date', '2014-01-01 00:00:00')`

Comment: "Tip: [If you want to keep your queries simple and easy to maintain, do not allow time components in your dates](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_dates.asp)!

Comment: I get the following error when trying this: `FatalErrorException: Parse Error: syntax error, unexpected 'bind' (T_STRING) in /var/www/Symfony/src/Acme/DemoBundle/Repository/PostRepository.php line 41`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
public function getPostCountByYear()
{
    $query = $this
        ->createQueryBuilder('post')
        ->where('post.created >= :begin')
        ->andWhere('post.created < :end')
        ->setParameter('begin', new \DateTime('2014-01-01 00:00:00'))
        ->setParameter('end', new \DateTime('2015-01-01 00:00:00'));

    $query->select('COUNT(post.created)');

    $year = $query
        ->getQuery()
        ->getSingleScalarResult();

    return $year;
}
```